# How to remove focus from QLineEdit when somewhere else clicked on the window PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qlineedit

## Problem

I want to Remove the Focus from `QLineEdit` when I click somewhere else on the window.
I'm using PyQt5 in Python 3.9.7 on Windows 10
I've also searched about this on google, youtube and stackoverflow. But Seems the api was outdated/Not for PyQt5.

## Code

I was Making a URL Shortener for Educational Purpose Only (Cz I'm Beginner:)
and I'm using My own class `Entrybox` which is parent to `QLineEdit`
Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from requests import get
from pyperclip import copy
from keyboard import add_hotkey


class Entrybox(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    pass

class Ui_window(object):
    def setupUi(self, window):
        self.win=window
        self.win.setFixedSize(400, 247)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        window.setFont(font)
        window.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        window.setStyleSheet("background-color: #484848;")
        window.setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(window)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 400, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color:#fff;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.boxurl = Entrybox(self.centralwidget)
        self.boxurl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 380, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.boxurl.setFont(font)
        self.boxurl.setStyleSheet("Entrybox {\n"
        "background-color: #595959;\n"
        "border:0px;\n"
        "color:#ffffff;\n"
        "selection-color: #ffffff;\n"
        "selection-background-color: #484848;\n"
        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
        "}\n"
        "Entrybox:hover {\n"
        "background-color: #636363;\n"
        "}\n"
        "Entrybox:focus {\n"
        "background-color: #636363;\n"
        "}")
        self.boxurl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.boxurl.setObjectName("boxurl")
        self.gobtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.gobtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 160, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.gobtn.setFont(font)
        self.gobtn.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.gobtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
        "background-color: #505050;\n"
        "border:0px;\n"
        "color:#ffffff;\n"
        "border-radius:15px;\n"
        "}\n"
        "QPushButton:hover {\n"
        "background-color: #595959;\n"
        "}\n"
        "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
        "background-color: #636363;\n"
        "}")
        self.gobtn.setObjectName("gobtn")
        self.boxname = Entrybox(self.centralwidget)
        self.boxname.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 380, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.boxname.setFont(font)
        self.boxname.setStyleSheet("Entrybox {\n"
        "background-color: #595959;\n"
        "border:0px;\n"
        "color:#ffffff;\n"
        "selection-color: #ffffff;\n"
        "selection-background-color: #484848;\n"
        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
        "}\n"
        "Entrybox:hover {\n"
        "background-color: #636363;\n"
        "}\n"
        "Entrybox:focus {\n"
        "background-color: #636363;\n"
        "}")
        self.boxname.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.boxname.setObjectName("boxname")
        self.status = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.status.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 210, 400, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.status.setFont(font)
        self.status.setStyleSheet("color:#fff;")
        self.status.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.status.setObjectName("status")
        self.titlelabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.titlelabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 250, 36, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.titlelabel.setFont(font)
        self.titlelabel.setStyleSheet("color:#fff;")
        self.titlelabel.setObjectName("titlelabel")
        self.boxtitle = Entrybox(self.centralwidget)
        self.boxtitle.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(55, 250, 336, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.boxtitle.setFont(font)
        self.boxtitle.setStyleSheet("Entrybox {\n"
        "background-color: #595959;\n"
        "border:0px;\n"
        "color:#ffffff;\n"
        "selection-color: #ffffff;\n"
        "selection-background-color: #484848;\n"
        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
        "}\n"
        "Entrybox:hover {\n"
        "background-color: #636363;\n"
        "}\n"
        "Entrybox:focus {\n"
        "background-color: #636363;\n"
        "}")
        self.boxtitle.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.boxtitle.setObjectName("boxtitle")
        self.urllabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.urllabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 99, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.urllabel.setFont(font)
        self.urllabel.setStyleSheet("color:#fff;")
        self.urllabel.setObjectName("urllabel")
        self.boxshorturl = Entrybox(self.centralwidget)
        self.boxshorturl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(115, 300, 277, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.boxshorturl.setFont(font)
        self.boxshorturl.setStyleSheet("Entrybox {\n"
        "background-color: #595959;\n"
        "border:0px;\n"
        "color:#ffffff;\n"
        "selection-color: #ffffff;\n"
        "selection-background-color: #484848;\n"
        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
        "}\n"
        "Entrybox:hover {\n"
        "background-color: #636363;\n"
        "}\n"
        "Entrybox:focus {\n"
        "background-color: #636363;\n"
        "}")
        self.boxshorturl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.boxshorturl.setObjectName("boxshorturl")
        self.copybtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.copybtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 340, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.copybtn.setFont(font)
        self.copybtn.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.copybtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
        "background-color: #505050;\n"
        "border:0px;\n"
        "color:#ffffff;\n"
        "border-radius:15px;\n"
        "}\n"
        "QPushButton:hover {\n"
        "background-color: #595959;\n"
        "}\n"
        "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
        "background-color: #636363;\n"
        "}")
        self.copybtn.setObjectName("copybtn")
        window.setFocus()
        window.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


        self.retranslateUi(window)
        self.UiSetup()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(window)

    def retranslateUi(self, window):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        window.setWindowTitle(_translate("window", "URL Shortener Online"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("window", "URL Shortener Online"))
        self.gobtn.setText(_translate("window", "Go"))
        self.status.setText(_translate("window", ""))
        self.titlelabel.setText(_translate("window", "Title:"))
        self.urllabel.setText(_translate("window", "Shorten URL:"))
        self.copybtn.setText(_translate("window", "Copy"))


    def UiSetup(self):
        add_hotkey('ctrl + c', self.copylink)
        self.boxurl.setPlaceholderText('Enter Long URL')
        self.boxname.setPlaceholderText('Enter Alias/Name (Optional)')
        self.gobtn.clicked.connect(self.shortenit)
        self.copybtn.clicked.connect(self.copylink)
        self.titlelabel.setHidden(True)
        self.boxtitle.setHidden(True)
        self.urllabel.setHidden(True)
        self.boxshorturl.setHidden(True)
        self.copybtn.setHidden(True)

    def showwarning(self,message,title='Error') -> str:
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
        msg.setText(message)
        msg.setWindowTitle(title)
        msg.exec_()

    def shortenit(self):
        url=self.boxurl.text()
        if 'http' not in url:
            url='http://'+url
        name=self.boxname.text()
        if name=='':
            api_url=f"https://cutt.ly/api/api.php?key=667cc3506cc77adad0b8503f2dfc8a2121930&short={url}"
        else:
            api_url=f'https://cutt.ly/api/api.php?key=667cc3506cc77adad0b8503f2dfc8a2121930&short={url}&name={name}'
        try:
            link=get(api_url).json()['url']
        except:
            self.showwarning('Please check your Internet Connection')
            return
        self.linkstatus=link['status']
        if self.linkstatus==7:
            self.status.setText('Done!')
            pass
        elif self.linkstatus==3:
            self.showwarning('Alias/Name is already taken')
            return
        elif self.linkstatus==2:
            self.showwarning('URL is Invalid or not supported')
            return
        elif self.linkstatus==5:
            self.showwarning('Entered Alias/Name in not supported')
            return
        else:
            self.showwarning('Something went wrong!')
            return
        
        self.shortlink=link['shortLink']
        self.title=link['title']
        self.titlelabel.setHidden(False)
        self.boxtitle.setHidden(False)
        self.urllabel.setHidden(False)
        self.boxshorturl.setHidden(False)
        self.copybtn.setHidden(False)
        self.win.setFixedSize(400,400)
        self.boxtitle.setText(self.title)
        self.boxshorturl.setText(self.shortlink)

    def copylink(self):
        try:
            copy(self.shortlink)
        except:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_window()
    ui.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You've included your cutt.ly API key in the question. That might be something you didn't want to do. If so then you might want to change your key?

Comment: Thanks. But It's a Fake Account's API verified with temp mail

Comment: You also apparently ignored the warning in the pyuic file you're trying to edit, which should clearly suggest you to ***not*** modify it. While not directly related to your issue, that's *still* an issue. Please read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: why don't you use the qt designer to set up your ui? so much handcoded stuff that can go wrong. let qt designer do the work for you. I never had such problems.

Comment: Yoo Man! I've Maked this GUI with Qt Designer. Then Converted it to Python with pyuic5. And One more thing, This Problem is default. Cz I saw it when I run it on Qt Designer. And I do not edited the setupUi and retranslateUi functions as default. I just added 4 more functions.